# How can I configure optparse to accept both parameter options as a command?

Tags: ruby, command-line, optparse

I'm using Ruby's `optparse` library to parse the options for my command line app but I can't figure out how to also accept a command.

It would be something like this:

```
commit -f -d init
```

`init` would be the command in this case. It isn't always required, as there is a default command that should be run if the user hasn't provided any.

Here's the code I have as of now:

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner  = %Q!Usage:
  pivotal_commit                                          # to commit with a currently started issue
  pivotal_commit -f                                       # to commit with a currently started issue and finish it
  pivotal_commit -d                                       # to commit with a currently started issue and deliver it
  pivotal_commit init -e "me@gmail.com" -p my_password -l #to generate a config file at the current directory!

  opts.on("-e", "--email [EMAIL]", String, "The email to the PT account you want to access") do |v|
    options[:email] = v
  end

  opts.on("-p", "--password [PASSWORD]", String, "The password to the PT account you want to access") do |v|
    options[:password] = v
  end

  opts.on("-f", '--finish', 'Finish the story you were currently working on after commit') do |v|
    options[:finish] = v
  end

  opts.on('-d', '--deliver', 'Deliver the story you were currently working on after commit') do |v|
    options[:deliver] = v
  end

  opts.on_tail('-h', '--help', 'Show this message') do
    puts opts
    exit
  end

  opts.on_tail('-v', '--version', 'Show version') do
    puts "pivotal_committer version: #{PivotalCommitter::VERSION}"
    exit
  end

end.parse!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command-line arguments(not options) are in `ARGV` after calling `OptionParser#parse!` because `#parse!` extracts options from `ARGV`.
So, you can get subcommand like this:

```
options = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
# definitions of command-line options...
# ...
end.parse!

subcommand = ARGV.shift || "init"

print "options: "
p options
puts "subcommand: #{subcommand}"
```

If you have many subcommands, [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki) gem might help you.

And, although this is not answer for your question, brackets([]) in option definition mean that the option's argument is optional.
For instance, at your definitions, email and password might be nil even when the options are passed:

```
$ pivotal_commit -e
options: {:email=>nil}
subcommand: init
```

If you require argument when the option is passed, remove brackets:

```
# ...
  opts.on("-e", "--email EMAIL", String, "The email to the PT account you want to access") do |v|
    options[:email] = v
  end
# ...
```

Now argument for email is required:

```
$ pivotal_commit -e
pivotal_commit:6:in `<main>': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
```